# Checking for homomorphisms between rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Firstly, apologies if this is not formatted correctly. Can somebody explain to me the general method for going about these questions? I know how to show that something is a ring homomorphism but I can't find them myself.

> Check if there exists any ring homomorphisms:
>
> $$i)\ ℤ → ℤ/5ℤ $$
> $$ii)\ ℤ/5ℤ → ℤ $$
> $$\ iii)\ ℤ/3ℤ → ℤ/6ℤ $$
> $$\ iv)\ ℤ/10ℤ → ℤ/5ℤ $$

Comment: The most important property is that if $f\colon R_1\to R_2$ is a ring homomorphism between $R_1$ and $R_2$, then $f(1_{R_1})=1_{R_2}$.

Comment: @Hasek No, that is rings with unit, or Unity rings, not the general rings.

Comment: @ZelosMalum Of course the OP assumes that the homomorphisms are unital, otherwise what's the point of his exercise, to say four times that there is the zero homomorphism?

Comment: Are you allowed to send $1\mapsto 0$?

Comment: The trivial homomorphism always exist so yes you can send 1 to 0. The image of it however will be the trivial ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the following result:

**Proposition:** Let $m,n\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ and $f\colon \Bbb{Z}_{m}\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_{n}$ be a map (we can think $\Bbb{Z}$ as $\Bbb{Z}_{0}$ and $\{0\}$ as $\Bbb{Z}_{1}$). Then $f$ is a ring homomorphism iff $n\mid m$. In such case $f$ is given by $$f(a+m\Bbb{Z})=a+n\Bbb{Z}.$$

*Proof:* I leave it to you to prove this proposition.

Now you can use the above result to your four maps using specific values. For example, if it exists a ring homomorphism $f\colon \Bbb{Z}_{3}\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_{6}$, then we would have $6\mid 3$, which is clearly false, so such a ring homomorphism doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps, I had came across that proposition somewhere but I don't think it said "iff" so I didn't think I was able to rule out the possibility of the existence of other homomorphisms in the case that n does not divide m. How would you use that for my my map from z to z/5z for example? z is not a modular ring

Comment: @McAttack you can always define $f$ as was given above, but is only a ring homomorphism exactly when $n\mid m$. For $\Bbb{Z}$, read the part that is written in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a ring homomorphism $\phi$ must be a homomorphism of Abelian groups. It must also take $1$ in the left ring  $R$ to $1$ in the right ring $S$.

Consider your first example $R=\Bbb Z$ and $S=\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$.
Can you find a group homomorphism from $R$ to $S$ that achieves $\phi(1)=1$?
And does this also preserve multiplication $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$?

Comment: You are going for the category of unital rings, not the category of rings. One ring may have a unit and the latter may not and it's still a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @ZelosMalum Perhaps the OP could clarify which category he/she is working in. My guess is that it is the category of unital rings. In the category of not-necessarily-unital rings the zero map is always a morphism, so the question would be rather idle.

Comment: The definition of a ring homomorphism we are given gives three properties to do with addition, multiplication and the unit of R going to the unit of S.